# Drag COUNTBLANK formula by intervales

Tags: excel

I have COUNTBLANK(sheet1!D3:G3) on the first row and I want COUNTBLANK(sheet1!D8:G8) on second row and COUNTBLANK(sheet1!D14:G14) on the third row, not COUNTBLANK(sheet1!D4:G4) and COUNTBLANK(sheet1!D5:G5).

I haven't tried yet, INDEX could be a solution, but I don't know how to apply to a reference that is a range...

Comment: `=COUNTBLANK(INDEX(Sheet1!D:G,3,))` change `3` to the row you need. If there's a logic between the number of rows between the previous and next row you could calculate the row number.

Comment: What's the pattern in the offsets?   In your sample,  the first offset is 5, the second is 6.  How does the pattern continue for subsequent rows?